# xdg-open: chrome/chromium/opera

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, opera, xdg-open

I have written an application that makes use of the pocket API. Currently the login is done inside a custom webframe of the application itself. But I want to use the default browser for this.

> Please send the user to the URL via their default browser in a new tab; do not present this page in a webview or screen within your application. Doing so violates Pocket's API guidelines.

To do this I need the browser to call the application after a successful login.
My callback looks something like this `pocketapp42://abcdefg`.

The desktop-file contains `MimeType=x-scheme-handler/pocketapp42;`

Everything works fine with browsers like Firefox, Midori, Epiphany and so on. `xdg-open pocketapp42://abcdefg` works as well. But Chrome, Chromium and Opera are confused and just google the link. However they handle `mailto` and `magnet` links just fine. Is there some kind of hardcoded list what types of links they will open and what types to simply ignore? This is really bugging me.

I need a way to call my application from ALL browsers with default browser settings so it will work for all users.

Comment: According to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/451350/chrome-doesn-t-handle-custom-protocols-correctly) answer, that might not be possible for Chrome(ium).